# Await response in worker thread from a class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, jira, worker

I have worker thread inside it i have called a class function that performs await operations.  I am  getting results as promise state pending. I cannot apply await in worker thread as it gives promise cannot be cloned exception.

I have attached code assume that code is working fine

I only need the awaited result of the class function  in worker.js
I only need ticketbinding response from class function getAttribute in worker

Any help will be appreciated .[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBu4v.png)

=================================================worker.js======================

```
const { parentPort, workerData } = require("worker_threads");
const ObjectParameters = require('./ObjectAttributes.js');

const execute = (workerData) => {
    return test(workerData.element, workerData.userDto);
};

parentPort.postMessage(execute(workerData));   // event handler

function test(element, userDto) {  // dont put aysn in worker thread  otherwise promise cannot be cloned exception
    var AttributeArray = new ObjectParameters.Attributes(userDto);
    var ticketBinding = AttributeArray.getTicketBindings(element);  // need this awaited result
    sleep(2000);
    if (ticketBinding !== null || ticketBinding !== undefined) {
        return ticketBinding;
    }


    var output = JSON.stringify(ticketBinding);
    if (output !== null | undefined) {
        return output;
    }

}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

==================================Class ===========================

```
var JiraApi = require('jira-client');
const utils = require('./Utils.js')
const Global = require('./Global.js')

class Attributes {

    _reponse;
    _params = {};
    _response = null;
    jira = null;
    constructor(userDto) {
        this.jira = new JiraApi({
            protocol: userDto.protocol,
            host: userDto.host,
            username: userDto.username,
            password: userDto.password,
            apiVersion: userDto.apiVersion,
            strictSSL: userDto.strictSSL
        });

    }
    async getAttributes(element) {
        this._response = await this.getIssue(element);
        this._params['sprintId'] = await this.getSprintId(this._response);
        this._params['Comments'] = await this.getComments(this._response);
        return this._params;
    }

    async getIssue(element) {

        var response = await this.jira.getIssue(element.id).then(function (response) {
            return response;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            return "undefined";
        })
        return response;
    }

    async getSprintId(response) {

        try {
            var sprint = response.fields.sprint;
            if ((sprint !== null) && (sprint !== undefined)) {
                var id = sprint.id;
                if ((id !== null) && (id !== undefined)) {
                    return id;
                }
            }
            return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";

        }
        catch (error) { // if incase connection breaks
            return "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
        }
    }


    async getComments(response) {

        try {
            var commentArray = [];
            var comments = response.fields.comment.comments;
            if ((comments !== null) && (comments !== undefined)) {
                if (comments.length !== 0) {
                    comments.forEach(element => {
                        commentArray.push(element.body);
                    });
                }
                return commentArray;
            }
            return [];
        }
        catch (error) {
            return [];
        }
    }

    getSprintName(response) {
        try {
            var sprint = response.fields.sprint;
            if ((sprint !== null) && (sprint !== undefined)) {
                var name = sprint.name;
                if ((name !== null) && (name !== undefined)) {
                    return name;
                }
            }
            return "";

        }
        catch (error) { // if incase connection breaks
            return " ";
        }
    }




    async getTicketBindings(element) {

        if (element.fields.issuetype.name == 'Bug') {
            var jiraResponse = await this.getAttributes(element);

            var ticketBinding = {
                ArtifactType: 'Ticket',
                ArtifactMode: "",
                ArtifactSteps: "",
                TicketNumber: null,
                ElementId: element.key,
                Summary: element.fields.summary,
                Description: utils.getFormatedDescription(element.fields.description),
                Assignee: "",
                Reporter: "",
                Priority_Enum: element.fields.priority.name,
                TicketType: "",
                State_Enum: element.fields.status.name,
                SprintID: jiraResponse.sprintId | "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",//await getSprintName(element.key, jira),
                Resolution: element.fields.resolution,
                Tags: utils.getLabels(element.fields.labels, element.key),
                Comments: jiraResponse.Comments | [] //await getComments(element.key, jira)
            };
            return ticketBinding;

        }
    }



}

module.exports = {
    Attributes: Attributes
}
```

Comment: All those `async` functions are guaranteed to return a `Promise` - as that is what `async` functions return by the very definition of [async function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#description) - *Each time when an async function is called, it returns a new Promise ....*

Comment: Uh, just use `parentPort.postMessage(await execute(workerData))` in your event handler?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65476158/worker-threads-cant-execute-promise-in-nodejs

Comment: parentPort.postMessage(await execute(workerData))  not worked

Comment: You need to wait for `AttributeArray.getTicketBindings(element)`.  Trying to trigger a delay in execution using `sleep` will not work.  (You’re not awaiting the call to sleep either.)

Comment: consider removed sleep then